# Dim brightness programmatically below Apple authorization

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, brightness

I'm developing an app where a screen need to be as dark as possible (the app need to run in a room all night long). 
I already set a black background and the brightness to 0 using :

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = (0.0)
```

But it's still too bright for a good comfort of use.

I've searched around the internet and found

```
UIScreen.main.wantsSoftwareDimming = true
```

That I put before my previous code line, but nothing changed.

I've tried the trick with accessibility settings and zoom things, that works well, but that's not a way I'm allowed to use.

So, I'm a bit out of idea and any help would be appreciated.

Is it even still possible to do it?
Is it possible to turn off the backlight? (That would be the best)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to keep an app running when the screen is off by setting the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` flag in your Info.plist.

It will only work if your app is in the foreground when the screen is turned off and it will disable any background mode for your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's good to know, and I'll definitely try.
But the thing is that I need to use the screen. 
The app has to recognize some gesture in order to do things after, that's why I was asking for the lowest luminosity.